# Is it possible to use Hibernate with PostgreSql's JSONB data type?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jsonb

Hibernate 5 does not support the PostgreSQL `jsonb` data type by default.

Is there any way to implement `jsonb` support for Hibernate + Spring JPA?

If there is a way, what are the pros and cons of using `jsonb` with Hibernate?

Comment: Please, don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Comment: Yeah, sure. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: It is now possible with Hibernate 6. See my answer below for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76193688/4845935

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Thanks [Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com) we have such opportunity! )

He created [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) lib:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

which adds a support of 'json', 'jsonb' and other types to Hibernate:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "int-array", typeClass = IntArrayType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private List<Child> children;

    @Type(type = "string-array")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text[]")
    private String[] phones;

    public Parent(String name, List<Child> children, String... phones) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
        this.phones = phones;
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Child implements Serializable {
    private String name;
}
```

More info: [1](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-hibernate-types-open-source-project-is-born/), [2](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-collections-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Thanks @Cepr0 for the answer. Actually, does this library support search by an object field? As I can see this library is pretty raw and community not really big, is it reliable?

Comment: @Aventes Vlad is one of the [Hibernate authors](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1025118/vlad-mihalcea)

Comment: @Aventes The [Hibernate Types framework](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) has over 750 GitHub stars and gets over 400k monthly downloads. So, the community is quite big because the Hibernate Types framework provides support for JSON, ARRAY, Inet, HStore, TSVector, DBs-specific Enums, YearMonth, and many other features.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Why do the Hibernate not support these types? Because they are not standard sql type?

Comment: JSON and ARRAY are standard, but thry are not supported by all DBs that Hibernate supports. One day, it might support the. In the meantime, you csn use the Hibernate Types project.

Comment: I tried to use these annotation directly on a JSONObject but get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypeBindings for class org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl with 2 type parameters: class expects 0". Have you any clue ?

Comment: javax.json.JsonObject I meant (sry). Same with Map<String, Object>

Answer (score 10):

### Update for Hibernate 6+ (2022+)

With the advent of Hibernate 6, mapping to PostgreSQL JSON(B) [has became possible out-of-the box](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-mapping-json).

One only needs to annotate the field with `JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)`.

**With non-typed JSON:**

```java
@Entity
public class Entity {
    ...
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private Map<String, String> payload;
    ...
}
```

(Although not every JSON will serialize into a Map).

**With JSON which is serialized as a custom Java type:**

```java
public class Foo implements Serializable {
  
    private String strValue;
    private Long longValue;
  
    public String getStrValue() {
        return strValue;
    }
  
    public void setStringProp(String stringProp) {
        this.strValue = strValue;
    }
  
    public Long getLongValue() {
        return longProp;
    }
  
    public void setLongValue(Long longValue) {
        this.longValue = longValue;
    }
}


@Entity
public class Entity {
    ...
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private Foo fooJson;
    ...
}
```

Please see this article for more examples:
https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/

Comment: Does not work. Despite @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON) on the entity field I am getting FIELD is of type jsonb but expression is of type bytea. Neither did @Type(JsonBinaryType.class) @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb") help. Hibernate is just a massive pain.

Comment: What adds insult to the injury is Hibernate team's response to community complaints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294493/4125622

Comment: @Phil I guess that it is probably not related to `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)` specifically. What is the sql column type and how do you fetch the data? HQL, native query, spring data jpa?

Answer (score 6):

[@Cepr0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5380322/cepr0)-s answer is correct but although I got some issues with it. I was getting exception when trying to use it with PostgreSQL `org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111`. Way to solve this, in my case, was adding custom hibernate dialect. [This](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/) resource might be helpful.

```
// CustomPostgreSQLDialect.java
public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {

    public CustomPostgreSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, StringArrayType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, IntArrayType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonStringType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonBinaryType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeStringType.class.getName());
    }
}
```

-

```
# application.yml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: "com.test.CustomPostgreSQLDialect"
```