# Save Nested POJO class Objects using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

## Class1:

```
int field2
Class2 field1
```

## Class2:

```
Class3 field3
```

## Class3:

```
String field4
String field5
```

## Class1 domain class:

```
@Table(name = "class1_details")
@Entity
public class Class1Details {
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "class2_fields")
    private Class2 fields;
  
     // respective getters and setters

}
```

I am using springboot. I am extending JPARepository for my repo interface. I want to save class1 in db. I am getting below exception:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not serialize;
> nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could
> not serialize ...
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not
> serialize ....
>
> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.model.Class3 ...

Tried @ElementCollection but of no use. Please help with this.

Comment: your entity class should implement `Serializable`

Comment: Got it. Now another exception.. 
 `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "class3_id" violates not-null constraint`
I havent declared any class3_id in class3. 
Do i need to create domain classes (@entity class) for class2 and class3 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make nested classes [@Embeddable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_component_embedded):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entities")
public class MyEntity {
    //...

    private MyData data;
}

@Embeddable
public class MyData {
    private String value;
}
```

Then Hibernate will deal with the following table:

```sql
create table my_entities (
  -- MyEntity stuff
  --
  value varchar(255)
);
```

---

Another an interesting approach is storing nested class in DB as **JSON**, see my related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49326794/5380322)...