Hibernate entity with dynamic database columns
I am trying to implement database entity with PanacheEntity. I am using hibernate ORM with panache extension for quarkus (https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache)
The columns are generated dynamically and therefore I used Map data structure to store keys and values.
This is my implementation:
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class MyEntity extends PanacheEntity {

  private Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();

  private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  public <T> T getField(String key, Class<T> valueType) {
    String value = fields.get(key);
    try {
      return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(value, valueType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed to deserialize value for key: " + key, e);
    }
  }

  public void setField(String key, Object value) {
    try {
      String stringValue = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(value);
      fields.put(key, stringValue);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed to serialize value for key: " + key, e);
    }
  }

  public Map<String, String> getFields() {
    return fields;
  }

  public void setFields(Map<String, String> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
  }

}

Upon starting application I get this exception:
JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>'

Does someone have some workaround for this issue?

Removed my prev comment, I think I understand what you're trying to achieve.  Hibernate doesn't know how to persist a map like that, that's what the error is.  It looks like you want something closer to a document store, i.e. persist an arbitrary structure.  Take a read of this: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persist-json-object

You need to store it as json, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76193688/2979325
